# Installing github application onto raspberry pi without setup.py

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to install a clock program to run on my Raspberry Pi from the repository https://github.com/sqeekypotato/kids_clock.

So far, I have used: `git clone https://github.com/sqeekypotato/kids_clock.git`

then

```
cd kids_clock
```

Only to then come to the realization that no `setup.py` file exists.

So my question is how do you go about running and installing the program other than with a setup file?

Comment: It is a flask app and so needs to be installed as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every github Python project comes ready for use with pip/easy_install, but when you attempt to run it sometimes you'll quickly figure out the dependencies.

By running `python app.py`, from the initial errors it appears to depend on flask and weather-api, so this worked for me:

```
pip install --user flask weather-api
python app.py
```

Then it tells you to go to the local URL showing something like this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this is great. Did you come across any skewing to a certain position in the browser window when you tested?

Comment: +1 for going the extra mile and testing the steps yourself.

Comment: Yeah it behaves strangely as I widen or shrink the window. If you take a look at the code in `templates/time.html`, it appears to be misusing Bootstrap Grids. See [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/grid/) for proper usage.